# Showing audio progress by progress bar in KivyMD

Tags: python, audio, progress-bar, kivymd

I'm making a meditation app with kivymd, and I'm trying to figure out how to connect a audio file to a progress bar. There are not too many videos on how to do it, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder 

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (400, 800)


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def play_sound(self):
        sound = SoundLoader.load("audio2/mp3.mp3")
        if sound:
            sound.play()

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(FirstWindow(name="First"))
sm.add_widget(SecondWindow(name="Second"))


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return Builder.load_file("thelab.kv")


MainApp().run()
```

kivy file -

```py
<SecondWindow>:

    MDIconButton:
        id: my_sound
        icon: "play"
        user_font_size: 150
        pos: 100, 100
        on_press:
            root.play_sound()

    MDProgressBar:
        id: progress_bar
        size_hint: .8, .5
        pos: 90, 200
        min: 0
        max: 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to handle it yourself. For that you can use `Clock.schedule_interval` to update the `MDProgressBar.value`.

1. First create prop. in your `SecondWindow` to bind to the prop. of `MDProgressBar`. Then schedule a callback say, `update_progress` to update the current progress. I also included the end case when the audio stops playing.

```py
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    length = NumericProperty(0.0)
    progress = NumericProperty(0.0)

    def play_sound(self):
        sound = SoundLoader.load("audio2/mp3.mp3")
        if sound:
            self.length = sound.length
            sound.play()
            # Now schedule and start updating after every 1.0 sec.
            # Use 'Clock.create_trigger' for more control.
            self.prog_ev = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_progress, 1.0)

    def update_progress(self, dt):
        if self.progress < self.length:
            self.progress += 1 # Update value.
        else: # End case.
            self.progress = 0 # Reset value.
            self.prog_ev.cancel() # Stop updating.
```

2. Now the binding work in `kvlang`; here also I added required logic to change icon automatically.

```py
<SecondWindow>:

    MDIconButton:
        id: my_sound
        icon: "pause" if root.progress else "play" 
        user_font_size: 150
        pos: 100, 100
        on_press:
            root.play_sound()

    MDProgressBar:
        id: progress_bar
        size_hint: .8, .5
        pos: 90, 200
        min: 0
        max: root.length
        value: root.progress
```